# Html.Partial work incorrectly when used with Layout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am setting Layout property of page like below. Because I have few different layouts so this one is different than in ViewStart.cshtml.

```
@{     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BaseLayout.cshtml"; }
```

Problem arise if my one of view call this view partialy . Even calling page By Html.Partial cause to render partial page with its layout.

I feel that this can be considered bug or wrong desing decision in ASP.Net MVC framework.

I am looking a way to fix this in elegant way. I have my own CustomWebViewPage that is interited from WebViewPage. I have overriden Layout property and if i can understand that view called as partialy so i can set Layout property null for fix this problem. But I am not sure that how can i understand it in my CustomWebViewPage.

Surely we can pass information by ViewData for tell WebViewPage it is partial or not but this is not quite elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

If you call your view using "return partialview()", it is rendered without layout.

```
public ActionResult MyPartialView()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: You are right so i removed that part from my question. Still Html.Partial render view itself with layout.